# Unable to download dependencies in SBT

Tags: sbt

I am trying to add below dependency but it is never resolved.

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.2"
```

Below are the versions used

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.7"
sbt.version = 1.2.4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding resolver in `plugin.sbt` as 
`resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"`

Comment: Not sure of compilation error but if you think dependencies got resolve you can accept the answer and, meanwhile, please post the error we can have a look and might help you.